# Obtaining the LogCat after the fact

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

So I wouldn't think I'm any different from any other hobbyist programmer: I like to use my own apps. While coding and debugging it is easy to watch exceptions flow and debug them but **what do you do when you find a crash case out in the wild: when you're no where near your tools?**

A bit more context:

My small app crashed today in a work meeting. I have a *rough* idea what caused it but I worry I won't be able to reproduce it when I get home to test in a controlled environment. Heck, my inclination of what caused it might be way off in the first place. I feel I need my LogCat but won't have access to it for another 8 hours *minimum*.

Are there methods to retrieve the crash data down the line? 
Is there a reliable pattern or function I can put in my code for this debug purpose?

I don't want to be writing my program in such a way that users are incumbered by Stack trace data in edge cases that my code has failed yet I definitely don't want my errors to vanish if I'm not plugged into Eclipse or otherwise.

Suggestions? Pointers?

Comment: Integrate a library like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in your app

Comment: I personally use an app called aLogcat to view the logs when a crash happens in the wild.  May have to be rooted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd suggest...

1. Override application class (in your app)
2. Set UncaughtExceptionHandler (-> application class)
3. Upon any "UncaughtException", either you can dump it in a pre-defined file (under app directory) or email it to an address
   (which you can bake-in your app.)

This way, you'd be able to save/track any unexpected crashes.

Hope this helps.